# How to make animation repeat on every keypress in unity (Unity3d, C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation, 3d

I am new to C# and Unity and I'm trying to figure out how to make an animation for an object in unity play when I press a key but I can only make the animation play once, and then it is broken and doesn't work. (I am trying to make an FPS game)

The code I have right now looks like this:

```
  void Start()
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
        gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = true;
    }       
}
```

When I press run and left click, the animation triggers and does as it is supposed to but when I try to do it again, the animation doesn't work. Can anybody help me change this code so that the animation will work and play every time the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your animation is non-looping as if it was looping it would already play back into itself when it is over.

One quick note I would have with your code is do not use GetComponent in an Update function as it is quite costly. An easy way to get an animation state to reset is to enable and disable it, however I am assuming you want to have more animations than shooting. You would want to look into what is called an Animation Tree or a [Blend Tree](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html) and add States to your animation. Examples of states would be an Idle, Walk, Run, Shoot, Crouch, etc. I would consider researching Animation Trees and Blend Trees to get a full animation cycle in.

Once you get a State machine working, I would have the enter go to an Idle state, then either set a transition Bool or directly switch the animation in code.

```
// when you serialize a private field, it will appear in 
// the inspector so you can drag in the reference in the editor
[SerializeField] private Animator anim = null;

private void Start()
{
     anim.enabled = false;
}

private void Update
{
     if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")
     {
          Shoot();
          if(!anim.enabled)
               anim.enabled;
          else
               anim.Play("AnimationStateName", -1, 0f);
     }
}
```

I have not tested the code, but I believe this would work with your setup. I would still strongly advise to not do this and look into Trees. After implementing the tree, instead of calling using the enabled, just use the line anim.Play("AnimationStateName", -1, 0f) or you can do anim.SetBool(isAttacking, true) if you set your state to transition from Idle/Run/Walk/etc. to Attacking when the isAttacking bool is set to true.

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVCsg_62xYw&ab_channel=Blackthornprod) that might help you out. I do not want to post a full explanation to animation states and blend trees, just point you in the right direction to a better approach.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this code out and do some research on animation trees and blend trees.

Comment: Let me know if you get any issues using it as it is untested. I am fairly sure it should work.

Comment: @v007 Just wanted to check-in. Did this end up working for you? If it did would you consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer to let others know who find your question that this is the solution. If not, what are the current errors/issues you are having?